# REST API Call via PHP cURL 500 server error

Tags: php, rest, api

I have the following code:

```
function callAPI($method, $url, $data, $auth){
   $curl = curl_init();

   switch ($method){
      case "POST":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         break;
      case "PUT":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
         break;
      default:
         if ($data)
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
   }

   // OPTIONS:
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Authorization: Basic '.$auth,
      'Content-Type: application/json',
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

   // EXECUTE:
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
   curl_close($curl);
   return $result;
}

    $data = ""; // some json data
$UserID = 'x';
$Password = 'y!';
$auth = base64_encode($UserID.':'.$Password);

    callAPI('POST','https://collaudo-wsrest.sda.it/SPEDIZIONE-WS-WEB/rest/spedizioneService',$data, $auth);
```

When executed, it returns 'connection error' (because I setup it), but specifically 500 server error.
The fact is, if I run my call here: https://reqbin.com/ it works perfectly. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Your method call has 4 parameters, but only 3 are defined in the function. You attempt to pass in `$auth`, but your function doesn't accept it... though you attempt to use it inside of the function.

Comment: If this script (as is with the error aynber mentions) runs on one host, but not another... it generally means you are using something that the php versions do/dont support (like curl is not part of the php install on the host that wont run the script). Looking at error logs helps eliminate these kinds of questions ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat I do not know the script they use in their website. But their call is correct, mine not for some reason.

Comment: Could you rephrase then in your question when you see the error, and when you do not. You say it works perfectly, but then does not... but now you say someone else's script works ok but then yours does not? First fix the error noted by aynber above.

Comment: @IncredibleHat https://reqbin.com/ this website uses a code (which I cannot see) that gives 200 as answer and returns values.
Now i'm trying to call this API too, but I get 500 server error. I tried cURL, xhttp, almost everything.

Comment: shouldn't you post some data with this POST request in order to make it work?

Comment: Your code is giving the 500 error, not the remote server. You need to check the error logs on your server, which will probably point to the issue in my second comment above.

Comment: @anynber https://reqbin.com/lbat8lv8 based on this, what's wrong in my code?